# sqlite3 c/c++, get the table names involved int an aggregate query

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I am using sqlite in a C++ project and I would like to be able to get the table names involved in a query.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
```

should return `Employee`

Now I use successfully `qlite3_column_table_name` ([doc](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_database_name.html)) for this kind of queries but for aggregate queries, the function returns null as the result does not belong to a table directly.

ex:

```
SELECT SUM(salary) AS total FROM Employee
```

Surely, when sqlite compiles the statement, the "Employee" keyword is recognised as a table. Do you know aby way to have access to this?
I tried to step through the code of the parser without success...

Comment: You are the one doing the query, don't you already know *what* table you're querying?

Comment: Well the user of the software can enter his own queries and we have objects watching changes in the tables involved in this user defined queries. So I want to exctract the table names from the query.

Comment: Having the user entering a generic, uncontrolled SQL query doesn't seems a good idea to me, unless you have a very limited, absoutely trusted and knowledgable users.  A better idea would be to have the user specifying his own selection criteria and build the query dinamically ensure is a valid and non-harmful query.

Comment: Thanks for you concerns Remo, our user are suposed to be programmers and they can make only read only requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [authorizer callback](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/set_authorizer.html) allows you to detect which tables are actually accessed by a query.